# How to reference CMake variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cmake

I use `execute_process` to run a shell script,

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ...) # here ... means many options
execute_process(
    COMMAND ./my_script.sh)
```

In `my_script.sh` I want to use the value of `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and how to do it?
When `echo ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}` in script, I get nothing.

Comment: Inside your Make file, you write the value of the variable into a file, and afterwards in your shell script, you read this file. However, in this case I would consider it the other way around: Set the variable in your script before invoking cmake, and pass it to the Makefile. No need of a temporary file then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake variables are not environment variables.

You can set an environment variable like so:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ...)
set(ENV{CMAKE_C_FLAGS} "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_script.sh")
```

Note that this lasts *only* for the duration of the CMake configure step. This means it will work with `execute_process`, but not `add_custom_command`.

Also note that calling a shell script from CMake is a code smell (hinders portability, is weird and probably unnecessary).

Comment: So some processing is needed to be done with shell before building the target, what's the correct way to do that if not calling a shell script?

Comment: "_needed_ to be done with _shell_" -- this is, let's say, rare.